# Using re.split() to work correctly with utf-8 text

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to split large russian text to words without sumbols '\s.,?!'.

Actually, I don't understand how use re.split() and re.findall correctly, because after I use them, it turn all words to utf-8 sumbols.

Thank you.

```
 file_read = None
    file_name = 'untitled.txt'
    with codecs.open(file_name, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as fin:
        file_read = fin.read()

words = re.split('u[\s.,?!]', file_read)
words = re.findall('\w+', file_read)
```

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 0):

This will retreive all russian words from the untitled.txt file

```
file_read = None
file_name = 'untitled.txt'
with codecs.open(file_name, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as fin:
    file_read = fin.read()
words = re.findall(ur'[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+', file_read)
```